# List all bamboo variables in inline script

Tags: bamboo

I have alot of Bamboo variables defined due the fact that i have a system with alot of legacy and config at places where it does not belong. Getting rid of all this will take a bit longer on the roadmap so i need to find a way to auto replace all these values.

The number im talking about is that there are 8 customer config files with each about 100 variables. Indeed, there was a maniac who added all of those in Bamboo because as you might thought most of them are variable for each environment.

At this moment i want to automate the deployment process and all is going fine exact the fact that i need to replace 100 variables and i dont want to maintain it in my script itself all the time.

I am looking for a way to retrieve all the variables in an array so i can just iterate through all the keys and try to replace them at the config files.
`echo "${bamboo.application.myvalue}"` will replace the value as expected. The only problem is, how can i get all the keys under bamboo.*

I tried it with the following functions but all without success:

- printenv
- env
- declare

All above without success. How can i retrieve a list of all those variables as inline script in Bamboo.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible to change the value of the variables on the fly. Instead, you can use the "Inject Bamboo variables" task in order to be able to change the variable value.
This task reads a file to create the variables. So, all you have to do is to create this file with the values you need, and then use this variables.

E.g.: Creating a file from a powershell script:

```
$path = 'bambooVariaveis.properties'
$connectionstringX = 'connectionstring="Data Source=XXXX;"'
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($path, $connectionstringX, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

E.g: Inject Bamboo Variables config

[image: Inject Bamboo Variables config]

Using it (in a subsequent script task):

```
echo ${bamboo.inject.connectionstring}
```